# PWABuilder app hanging sometimes after first opening the app on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, pwabuilder

We have built a new Progressive Web Application (PWA) hosted in our SAP Spartacus platform, and we used the PWABuilder.com site to create a deployment package for the Apple app store so that our customers could find the app there. The creation of the deployment package went fairly well, and although we have yet to submit the app for review to Apple, we have been testing it on our iphones after downloading from TestFlight.

We've encountered a bit of an annoying problem that seems to be happening only on iphones, and the problem is that when first opening the app on the iphone, the app loading screen will appear to hang for up to 90 seconds before finally letting us in the app. All of us that are testing have used different iphones, and we all have encountered the problem. The problem doesn't always happen, and sometimes when it does happen, it only lasts a few seconds instead of the full 90 seconds. This problem is not happening on our Android test phones, and it also does not seem to happen when we run this app from a browser on our desktops.

In troubleshooting this problem, I've attached my iphone to my mac and started up the app so that I can see console output in xcode. I can pretty consistently see the problem occur like this, and a message that I see appear in the console after a few seconds is the following:

```
[ProcessSuspension] 0x15482a6b0 - TimedActivity::activityTimedOut:
```

After some googling, this problem seems to be pointing to WKWebView. I'm not an iphone developer so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this further. I was thinking of maybe trying to add some debug statements to the package that PWABuilder provided to see if I could find the exact line of code that's executing when the problem happens.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what else I could do to troubleshoot this? Does anyone have any idea of what may be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

We solved this problem, and it was due to the service worker. I don't remember specifically what it was about the service worker that was broken, but after some retooling of the service worker code, the problem with the hanging app went away.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/